# Selenium C#: Adding explicitwait function

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to add an explicit wait function to my project but I am receiving an error

```
namespace AutoProj
{
    enum PropertyType
    {
        Id,
        Name,
        LinkText,
        CssName,
        ClassName
    }

    class PropertiesCollection
    {
        //autoimplemented properties
        public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
    }
```

main.cs

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]

[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
        {

          [Test]
          public void TestCase_Abc()
          {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, 1000) ;
```

Error at **`(PropertiesCollection.driver, 1000)`**. Am I missing something in here?

Error Description:

> Error 1: The best overloaded method match for
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait.WebDriverWait(OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver,
>   System.TimeSpan)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2: Cannot convert fron 'int' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your `PropertiesCollection` class is private (default in C#), make it public (it looks like separate classes from what you posted).
- `WebDriverWait` gets time span `new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));`

Comment: Another question: I am receiving error at nest line. at until and ExpectedCondition   `wait.until(ExcepctedConditions.elementToBeClickable(NextTab));` Do you know why?

Comment: `[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Next Tab")]
 public IWebElement NextTab { get; set; }`

Comment: @AJ1110 in C# it should be `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.LinkText(""Next Tab")));`

Comment: Note the capital letter in `ElementIsClickable` and `Until`

Comment: 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions' does not contain a definition for 'ElementIsClickable'

Comment: Oh got it it should be `ElementToBeClickable`

Comment: Thanks @guy. Appreciate your help.